# obtain specific order of data with the %in% command

Tags: r, subset

Take the following example. We generate a series of data frames that are based on `cx` values.

In the third example, where we generate `df4`, I want the data.frame to be formatted in a way that the data corresponding to `c==2` is in the first row. Such that the command `head(df4$A)` returns `[1] 2 1 4`

```
# data to play with
set.seed(123)
A <- c(1:10)
B <- sample(5:9,10,replace = T)
df1 <- data.frame(A,B)

# the values of interest
t1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
# subset df1 based on t1
df2 <- subset(df1, df1$A %in% t1)
head(df2$A)

# again the values of interest
t2 <- c(2,3,4)
# subset df1 based on t2
df3 <- subset(df1, df1$A %in% t2)
head(df3$A)

# once again the values of interest
t3 <- c(2,1,4)
# subset df1 based on t2
df4 <- subset(df1, df1$A %in% t3)
head(df4$A)
```

Comment: `df1[match(t3, df1$A),]` ? Maybe you should look at `?merge`

Comment: Mind that you will obtain NA rows if t3 isn't a subset of df1$A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use order():

```
> df4[order(t3) , ]
  A B
2 2 8
1 1 6
4 4 9
```

Answer (score 1):

@42- was quicker :) for the record:

Order the Data frame

```
df4[order(t3),] 
#  A B
#2 2 8
#1 1 6
#4 4 9
```

Order the vector

```
df4$A[order(t3)] 
#[1] 2 1 4
```